# Is it okay to put rechargeable AA batteries into the EV3?

Tags: ev3

Is it really okay to put rechargeable AA batteries into the EV3 and continuously put them in after recharging them each time? Boring old one-use AA batteries are getting too expensive for me, and I know that I should use the rechargeable battery which is intended for EV3. But still, will it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the posts in [this Eurobricks thread](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/153021-6-li-po-aa-to-be-used-in-ev3-mindstorms/), it is indeed possible, even if there are a few caveats to keep in mind (like the maximal current the batteries can supply versus the maximal current the attached motors can draw).

Comment: And I see some other guy use them, even though TLG clearly states that they are NOT recommended.

Comment: TLG has no other choice than to say they are not recommended, in order to shield themselves from the legal liability in case some faulty rechargeable batteries leak or explode, damaging the EV3 or other property or life. Then all the lawyers have to do is point at the clause that "these are NOT recommended" and a lengthy and costly legal battle is avoided.